# Using the result of one R function in another R function

Tags: r, function

I am very very new to R and programming in general and I am asking this question as part of a degree program.  Don't worry, our professor said we could use StackOverflow.  So here is my question: our first requirement is to create a function that returns `TRUE` or `FALSE` based on a passing grade score of 70.  Here is my code for this:

```r
passGrade <- function(x) {
 if(x>=70) {
  return('TRUE')
 }
 return('FALSE')
}
```

The second requirement is to use the results from this function and write a new function that will print "Congrats" is `TRUE` and "Try Harder!" if `FALSE`.  It seems like I need to store the results of the first set of code as a variable, but when I do that it is not correctly read in the second code set. Here is my failed attempt

```r
passGrade <- function(x) {
 if(x>=70) {
  x <- return('TRUE')
 }
 x <- return('FALSE')
}

Message <- function(x) {
 if(x == 'TRUE') {
  return("Congrats")
 }
 return("Try Harder!")
}
```

I am sure there is a super simple solution to this, but I am not having any luck.

Comment: (1) Are you intending to return the strings of `'TRUE'` and `"FALSE"`, or the R native objects `TRUE`/`FALSE`? I suggest the latter, which is more idiomatic and efficient (imo). (2) Nested function calls are natural in any language, such as `f(1)` and `g(...)` can be combined as `g(f(1))`. What have you tried? What failed?

Comment: Other thoughts, hope you find them helpful: (1) no need to capture the return value from `return`, it immediately exits the function with its argument as the return value to the function, so `x` is ignored in `passGrade`. (2) if you agree that using strings should be changed to boolean objects, then `passGrade <- function(x) return(x >= 70)` (or just `function(x) (x >= 70)`, since the last expression/value is automatically returned) is enough and much more idiomatic/succinct.

Answer (score 2):

Below is a simple solution, you can directly return `TRUE` or `FALSE` based on the condition and then pass this to `Message` function to print out the required output, as shown below:

```
passGrade <- function(x) {
  if(x>=70) {
    return(TRUE)
  }
  return(FALSE)
}

Message <- function(x) {
  if(x == TRUE) {
    return("Congrats")
  }
  return("Try Harder!")
} 

Message(passGrade(60))
Message(passGrade(80))
```

Output:

```
[1] "Congrats"
[1] "Try Harder!"
```